# Cannot pass 2 word argument

Tags: javascript, php

I try to make a POST request. The server should execute peer_id_write.php with argument containing user name.
When user name is one word the code works okay.
But when the user name is 2 words (eg Ian Caple) i see error in debug screen: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list.
When I try to rawurlencode() the user name I encounter the following error: SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token.

How to write the code correctly?

Heres my code:

```
<?php
$user=rawurldecode($_GET['user']);
?>

<script>
    req.open("POST", "peer_id_write.php?peer="+<?php echo $user; ?>);
//    req.open("POST", "peer_id_write.php?peer="+<?php echo rawurlencode($user); ?>);
</script>
```

Comment: Use `urlencode()`instead

Answer (score 0):

Consider the contexts involved and how this is expanding for `$_GET['user']` of `"example"`:

```
req.open("POST", "peer_id_write.php?peer="+example);
```

That's just trashed now. Use [`json_encode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php):

```
req.open("POST", "peer_id_write.php?peer="+<?php echo json_encode($user); ?>);
```

Now that expands properly:

```
req.open("POST", "peer_id_write.php?peer="+"example");
```